# AS3 Error 1180 Call to a possibly undefined method in IntelliJ

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I am getting compiler error:
 `Error 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method` when all imports are ok and all method definitions are ok in IntelliJ, double checked?

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble, but solution was very easy. One of my package in project was with name "notification" and it had conflict with standart package name, so i had changed name to "notificationS" and compilier had began work without erros.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you did some refactoring on the class that you are getting the error, you have to go to menu:

> Build > Rebuild Project

If you just do debug or run, it doesnt work for some reason.

I am not sure if the reason is simple refactoring or some git merge, but solution is here.